# Google block CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

I have a register form from ion_auth and when I send the form, I get an error that I can't send form. After, google sends me an email that someone wanted something sent from my account and was blocked...

```
$config['use_ci_email'] = TRUE; // Send Email using the builtin CI email class, if false it will return the code and the identity
$config['email_config'] = array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'my@gmail.com', // actual values different
    'smtp_pass' => 'my password',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'newline' => '\r\n',
);
```

Comment: It's just because of your server! You can try alternatives like mailgun

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your email (the `my@gmail.com`) account and enable access from *Less secure apps*. Go to this address: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps when you are logged into your gmail account and flip the switch there.

Comment: is there another way? Because if I change the server (new ip) google ask me again for confirmation.... by the way what I can do if I don't want have google account? This work only with google?

Comment: How frequently are you planning to change IPs? Is that really a problem? You can create a google account for free, it will let you send 2000 emails a day. `This work only with google?` - Your code will work with any SMTP server. You can create account at Yahoo for example and use their SMTP [settings](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4075.html), I don't know how many mails they let you send a day though.